# Eigenvalues of $ADA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Consider a rectangular matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ and a diagonal matrix $D\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$. What can one say on the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $ADA^T$?

For example, if we denote $\{d_i\}_{i=1..N}$ the diagonal components of $D$ and $A=U\Sigma V^T$ is its singular values decompositions, can you express the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $ADA^T$ in some simple way using $D,U,\Sigma,V$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $(ADA^T)^T = ADA^T$.  Since $ADA^T$ is symmetric, its eigenvalues are real and we may select an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors by the [spectral theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)

Besides that, note that if $A$ is square, the product is [congruent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) to $D$.  If $A$ also has full rank, then [Sylvester's law of inertia applies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).

Comment: Thanks. For the general rectangular $A$ case you just state that the eigenvalues are real, right? I'm hoping they can be related to $d_i$ and $\sigma_i$, the diagonal elements of $D$ and $\Sigma$.

Comment: Not really.  For example, if each $d_i > 0$, then for any symmetric matrix $B$: there exists an $A$ such that $ADA^T = B$.